# Installing Ubuntu on SSD And using HDD as home

Tags: partitioning

Hey guys I have both SSD and HDD in my device and I have a question concerning partitioning. Whenever I create home partition on my HDD most of the deb packages and flatpaks are being installed there such as web browsers but I want to be able to install them on SSD how can I do that? can someone help me?

Comment: You get most control in your directory layout.  As *deb* packages expand to specific locations on your file-system, your control over that is to place those directories on the drive/array you want them to be, with `ubiquity` & `ubuntu-desktop-installer` (even `calamares` as used by some *flavors*) allowing you control over directories in the "*Something else*" or "*Manual Partitioning*" option of install (you didn't specify Ubuntu product thus we don't know which installer you're using; I haven't even touched `subiquity` of Ubuntu Server for example).

Comment: The app should still be in / (root). But data may be in the . (hidden) files & folders in /home. I know that is where both Firefox & Thunderbird defaults are. I make / a bit larger and keep /home inside /. but then have all data in separate data partition. I use links to then make folders in data partition look like they are in /home. Links
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2488332